# Recommendation for a ASP.NET Webforms Validation Framework

Tags: asp.net, validation

I have worked with the .MVC framework using validation frameworks such as [xVal](http://xval.codeplex.com/) or [FluentValidation](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com).

Is there anything similar available for webforms as well? I have got a few projects which have to be done using webforms.

What I'm asking for is some kind of integration with the webforms infrastructure. I could just use one of the mentioned frameworks in order to validate the (view/page)models, but I still would have to do a lot of form validation in the page.

Thanks for any answers in advance. I'd really appreciate if you could describe or refer to the level of webforms integration.

Comment: I disagree with the "not constructive" judgment. I had almost precisely the same question, and Google led me here, but the "best" answer for my use case isn't listed: SpecExpress (http://specexpress.codeplex.com/documentation). If the question were open I could add it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a project in codeplex trying to port xVal to Webforms, take a look at http://xvalwebforms.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at the Validation Application Block from the Enterprise Library. I've never tried to integrate it using webforms, but it does have a page dedicated to just that. Maybe this is something that can help:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc309331.aspx

Comment: Also look at the following article when doing VAB ASP.NET integration: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/ApplicationBlock.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Peter Blum's Data Entry Suite: http://www.peterblum.com/Home.aspx